# Set Current caretposition in viewport Top wpf richtextbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, panning

I am working in WPF. I want to show current caretposition in viewport top. I already tried the `BringIntoView()` Method. It works, but it only working moved to hide part.

```
FrameworkContentElement fce = (mycaret.Parent as FrameworkContentElement);
if (fce != null)
{
    fce.BringIntoView();
}
```

I got an other method in this below code.

```
System.Windows.Rect rc = currentline.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward);
rtb.ScrollToVerticalOffset(rc.Bottom + rtb.VerticalOffset - txtAppendValue.ViewportHeight);
```

It gives bottom up panning. So how can I get top down panning through this way?